# Open newly added document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Windows XP, Office 2007 and the Microsoft Custom UI Editor for building add-ins.

I'm creating an add-in which simply opens some pre-defined word .dotx templates. But I've ran into an od problem.

The new word document simply won't activate. I think it's because each user either use two or three monitors, but I'm not sure how to handle such a setup in VBA.

Also, it's only sometimes the new document won't activate. Whenever a userform is present in the code it seems to bug.

With activate I mean the user is presented with the "old" document, and the new opened document doesn't get the focus.

Anyways, here's the code that won't get i to work:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

If Me.chbxFigures = False Then
    If Me.obtnDanish Then
        Set newDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="path", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
    ElseIf Me.obtnEnglish Then
        Set newDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="path", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
    End If
ElseIf Me.chbxFigures Then
    If Me.obtnDanish Then
        Set newDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="path", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
    ElseIf Me.obtnEnglish Then
        Set newDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="path", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
    End If
End If

'Documents.Add.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate
newDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
newDoc.ActiveWindow.Activate
newDoc.Activate
Set newDoc = Nothing

Unload Me

End Sub
```

And this code seems to work fine:

```
Sub LoadSC(control As IRibbonControl)
    Set newDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="path", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
    newDoc.Activate
    newDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    newDoc.ActiveWindow.Activate
    newDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Activate
    Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Google hasn't come up with an answer in two days, so I hope some of you might lead me in a helpfull direction.

Comment: but what is your question? I understand that you have a problem but you have also provided solution, so... use code which work fine as it looks fine.

Comment: Is your form `ShowModal = True`? You can move the `Unload Me` above the `newDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True`. Codes after unload Me will still get executed.

Comment: @PatricK Moving the Unload me before the newDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True did the trick!

Thanks - don't know if I'm able to mark you comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment and confirmation, moving the `Unload Me` above the line `newDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True` will solve this issue - possibly the Form is stopping the launch of new document.

In VBA, codes are still executed until `End Sub/Function` or `Exit Sub/Function`.